# Animation, increase and decrease the size

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with the animation, I want the heart to start small, increase and then decrease in size, as shown in the gif below.

**Desired animation**

[image]

But the current behavior is that the heart starts out big and then slows down.

[image]

Would anyone know what it would take to fix the animation?

Here is the flutter code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage();

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> _heartAnimation;
  AnimationController _heartController;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _heartController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _animate() {
    _heartController
      ..reset()
      ..forward(from: 0.0)
      ..reverse(from: 1.0);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final quick = const Duration(milliseconds: 500);
    final scaleTween = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0);
    _heartController = AnimationController(duration: quick, vsync: this);
    _heartAnimation = scaleTween.animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _heartController,
        curve: Curves.elasticOut,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ScaleTransition(
          scale: _heartAnimation,
          child: Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 160.0, color: Colors.red),
        )
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _animate();
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.favorite_rounded),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code, it works for me perfectly. If you have any questions please let know.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage();

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> animation;
  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final quick = const Duration(milliseconds: 500);
    final scaleTween = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0);
    controller = AnimationController(duration: quick, vsync: this);
    animation = scaleTween.animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: controller,
        curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
      ),
    )..addListener(() {
      setState(() => scale = animation.value);
    });
      
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _animate() {
    animation
    ..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
      if (scale == 1.0) {
        controller.reverse();
      } 
    });
    controller.forward();
  }

  double scale = 0.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: scale,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
            size: 160.0,
            color: Colors.red
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _animate();
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.favorite_rounded),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired animation using the zoom-in effect, we can learn it through the [Flutter doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScaleTransition-class.html), or refer to the code below:

```
class _ManageScale extends State<YourClass> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

late final AnimationController controller = AnimationController(
 duration: const Duration(seconds:2),    
vsync: this,
)..repeat(reverse:true) ;
late final Animation<double> _animation = CurvedAnimation(
parent: _controller,
curve:Curve.fastOutSlowIn,  
);

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ScaleTransition(
          scale: _animation,
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: <Place_Your_Heart_Shape>(size: 150.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
`


class _ManageScale extends State<YourClass> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

late final AnimationController controller = AnimationController(
 duration: const Duration(seconds:2),    
vsync: this,
)..repeat(reverse:true) ;//putting repeat reverse true is make your container big and small in same order

late final Animation<double> _animation = CurvedAnimation(
parent: _controller,
curve:Curve.fastOutSlowIn,  
);

//for proper implementation of above stateful widget see doc

now use above animation as a property in your widget which is _animation

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ScaleTransition(
          scale: _animation,
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: <Place_Your_Heart_Shape>(size: 150.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```